# Asp.Net MVC Angularjs Unit testing without nodejs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

The application I am currently working have a Asp.Net MVC serving up the pages and angularjs on the client side. I am looking to set up the unit testing on the angularjs controllers, services. Is there a way to set up unit testing for angularjs scripts without NodeJs. Or is the only way to Unit test the client side contollers through Grunt, Jasmine and Karma and mentioned on most of the articles.
Thank you

Comment: This question is too broad.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a preferred way among the asp.net mvc community to unit test angularjs controller with out installing nodejs.

Comment: Try https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/

Answer (score 0):

After reading through a few blog post was able to accomplish this with chutzpah test runner and Jasmine nuget package for chutzpah. Might not be the most elegant solution but it works as per the given parameters on the task